# /cygdrive/c and C:\ are different

Tags: c, cygwin, mount, windows-8.1

I'm trying to run batch scripts via OpenSSH on Windows 8.1 but I'm getting this message:

```
bash: /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/boot8.bat: No such file or directory
```

Somehow, the cygwin environment doesn't map C:\ to /cydrive/c correctly

Just to make sure, this is what mount says:

```
$ mount
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

So, using cygwin shell I get this result:

```
$ ls -Al /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32 | grep  boot
-rwxrwx---+  2 TrustedInstaller TrustedInstaller     3072 Aug 22 06:14 api-ms-win-base-bootconfig-l1-1-0.dll
-rwxrwx---+  2 TrustedInstaller TrustedInstaller  3170304 Jun 18 14:43 boot.sdi
-rwxrwx---+  2 TrustedInstaller TrustedInstaller    79360 Aug 22 05:49 bootcfg.exe
```

If I however use the cmd window I can see the file:

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir | findstr boot
22/08/2013  12:21           165,376 bcdboot.exe
18/06/2013  16:08         3,170,304 boot.sdi
01/08/2013  15:24               290 boot7.bat
04/11/2013  16:00               298 boot8.bat
22/08/2013  12:15            87,040 bootcfg.exe
22/08/2013  10:17            13,312 bootim.exe
22/08/2013  13:45           109,408 bootsect.exe
22/08/2013  12:44             2,560 bootstr.dll
22/08/2013  10:07         3,311,616 bootux.dll
19/11/2013  16:42               307 bootxp.bat
```

Using the windows explorer, I can see the boot8.bat too.

It works under Windows XP and Windows 7. It doesn't matter whether or not you use capital letters for the Windows and system32 directory . I had this problem before, where I would edit files with notepad++ and when I later opened them with notepad they didn't change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try that `ls -al /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32 | grep -i boot`

Comment: it's possible that windows is redirecting your access to the system32 directory to syswow64 because your cygwin installation is 32bit

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I just did a symbolic link with ln -s on the XP and Win7 machines so I could use the same script.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ls -Al /cygdrive/c/Windows/sysnative | grep boot
```